# Loop through a workbook daily and copy sheets to another workbook based on tab name

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a workbook that I run daily and this creates multiple tabs called system 1, system 2, system 3 etc.. I then manually copy each tab to a file called the same as the tab name ie system 1.xlxs after the data from previous days .. the source data starts in Cell B2 and goes to Column J and could be any length the destination data starts in Column F to N.

The destination files are stored in folders called Month & Year ie Z:/Results/June 20/

I worked out how to update the tabs by looping but just can't get my head around opening the files and copying the data at the bottom

```
Public Ws As Worksheet
Sub Loop_Thru_shts()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Ws.Activate
        If ActiveSheet.Name = "Macro" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "RC Common" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "RC Data" Then
            'nothing
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$1500").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Y"
        End If

    Next Ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Worksheets("RC Data").Activate

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help